# How to connect to a computer with db25 without screen?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, serial-port

I have and old computer and I need to install Ubuntu server on it but I don't have a VGA monitor, what I do have is access to  a db25 to usb cable and a laptop with SSH client. Is there any way I can use it to connect to it without having a screen?

The old computer runs windows XP professional and it's 32bits.

This is the port i plan to use:

[image: db25 port on top of 2 VGA ports]

Comment: XP doesn't really have a text mode command interface unless you have telnet or cygwin installed, so while I'm just guessing, I don't think you are going to be able to get a console session over serial. additionally I don;'t think it will help with ubunutu installation. you are probably better off using a vga to dvi adapter and a dvi to hdmi adapter

Comment: Server-class hardware often provides a Serial console independent of the OS, but that's because the BBMC is set up to do that.  I seriously doubt that PC would, but if you had the manufacturer/model of the mainboard, you could check and see if that's an option they provided.  Unfortunately, even if it was, you'd probably need a VGA monitor to configure it in BIOS.  Best bet is get a cheap VGA monitor or adapter.

Comment: Additionally, a purple DB-25 denotes a Parallel port.  Your serial port is the DB-9 below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly – if you find a cable for the DE-9 port instead. Although DB-25 was sometimes used for serial, that won't be the case on a PC this new; as Chris already mentioned, purple indicates it's a parallel (LPT) port and most software isn't designed to use LPT ports in this way.

With an actual serial-to-USB cable, the next step would be to remove the disk with Windows (or make it unbootable by erasing the MBR), as then the computer will *probably* end up booting from your Ubuntu CD or USB stick instead. (At that point, a SATA disk can be connected again.)

The install media for the "Server" variant of Ubuntu [supports using the serial console](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general) for the installer. You'll probably need to manually edit grub.cfg (or isolinux.cfg or whatever Ubuntu's install media uses) to add `console=ttyS0` to the kernel command line.

After the system is installed, add the same option to the kernel command line of the installed system, or enable the `serial-getty@ttyS0` service. As Ubuntu uses GRUB, it is possible to edit its grub.cfg to let you see the GRUB boot menu through serial port as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Is there any use for the db25 parallel port apart from printing or should I just leave it alone?

Comment: There used to be software that could use it for networking and file transfer (e.g. LapLink or MS-DOS INTERLNK), but on your machine it's easier to use Ethernet for that purpose. It is apparently possible to use `console=lp0` with Linux – though with the docs being written for kernel 2.2 I don't know if that's _still_ possible – but most systems handle it as specifically a printer port and not as a general-purpose one; e.g. the machine on the USB end of your DB25-to-USB cable probably won't even list it as an available terminal port.